# Maintaining a shared folder between consumer and producer (both are constantly running)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I am looking for the best possible option to design a solution to this problem, where I have a producer(Kafka) which is writing to a folder in S3, and a consumer, periodically reading from the same folder every 15/30 mins, now how to maintain the updates coming from the producer. 
The requirement is :

1. Each time the consumer run, it get all the newly added files since last run.
2. If the producer is writing some file at the same time when consumer is running, the consumer should ignore it and consider it
   in the next run. In other words, the consumer should take a snapshot
   of folder at starting point, where snapshot includes all the
   completed copied files.
3. After the consumer copies the files, the copied ones should be deleted, so as to not be considered for the next run and keeping the
   folder size in check.

As my folder is in S3 and is written by kafka S3 connector, is there an available technology option on consumer side which can handle this situation, if not, how to go about designing one?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect might be worth looking into but I think you can solve this solution with regular producer/consumers. For your first cocern, as long as the consumer is set to startup at the last commited offset the consumer will know to get the newly added files. You just need to make sure to manual handle consumer offset commiting rather than using automatic commits. For the second concern, s long as the producer does not commit it's offset until it is finished writing to S3 the consumer will never know to look for the file. For your final concern you can have the consumer clean up the file after it's read but then you'd lose any of the reprocessing advantages of kafka.